# Krull dimension in equivariant cohomology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let a compact Lie group $G$ act on a manifold $X$.  Let $\mathbb Q$ be the field of rational
numbers and assume that cohomology $H^{\ast} (X)$ with $\mathbb Q$-coeffiecients is 
finite-dimensional.  It seems to be a folklore fact that the Krull dimension
of the  even-dimensional $G$-equivariant cohomology $H^{even} _G (X, \mathbb Q)$ coincides with
the maximal rank of the stabilizers of $G$.

The corresponding result in cohomology with $\mathbb F_p$ coefficients is proven
as Theorem 7.1  in D. Quillen's paper   "The spectrum of an equivariant cohomology ring. I",  Ann. of Math. (2) 94 (1971), 549-579.

With rational coefficients, I have only found this result in the case where $G$ is a torus.
It is quite easy  to reduce the  case of a general compact Lie group $G$ to the commutative case.  But I assume that the result for general compact Lie group $G$ has appeared somewhere.

Does somebody know a reference for this fact?

Comment: With rational coefficients the cohomology should be invariants of the cohomology of the torus by the Weyl group, which shouldn't change the Krull dimension.

Comment: (Sorry, the above comment is for the case $X = pt$!)